# F# Type Provider compiled as *.exe file

Tags: f#, type-providers

Why I cannot create Type Provider as *.exe file with `[<TypeProviderAssembly()>]` and `[<EntryPoint>]` inside?

When I try to reference such TP using `#r @"d:\TP\bin\Debug\MyTypeProvider.exe"`, I see the following:

`test.fsx(3,1): error FS3031: The type provider 'd:\TP\bin\Debug\MyTypeProvider.exe' reported an error: Assembly attribute 'TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute' refers to a designer assembly 'MyTypeProvider' which cannot be loaded or doesn't exist. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///d:\TP\bin\Debug\MyTypeProvider.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I need to have a type inference runtime in separate process, because it should be `64bit` (unlike `32bit` VS process). But I want to pack all things into one file, reference it from VS and start as external process.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's some good underlying reason for always looking for DLLs instead of EXEs, but I suspect this may be an arbitrary limitation.

I can get things to work in FSI if I supply the assembly's full name to the `TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute` constructor (e.g. `[<TypeProviderAssembly("MyExe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")>]`), but IntelliSense doesn't work and I can't use the TP from other projects.  Consider filing a bug with the team - but it would probably help if you could justify why you need an EXE instead of a DLL for your scenario.

Comment: TP should be able to connect to SharePoint. It is possible only from `64bit` process. VS is `32bit` app that mean that IntelliSense too. I cannot do it directly from type provider. The only possible solution that I see is to start separate `64bit` process and communicate between them using WCF named pipes. It will be nice to pack service and client into one exe.

Comment: You can look at the [current implementation](https://github.com/sergey-tihon/PowerShellTypeProvider). But I want to merge these projects into one. I think that in this case it will be easier to use.